# Conditionally calling an API using React-Query hook

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using react-query to make API calls, and in this problem case I want to only call the API if certain conditions are met.

I have an input box where users enter a search query. When the input value is changed, a search server is called with the contents of the input as the search query ... but only if the input value is more than 3 chars long.

In my react component I'm calling:

```
const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(['search', searchString], getSearchResults);
```

And my `getSearchResults` function will, conditionally, make an API call.

```
const getSearchResults = async (_, searchString) => {
    if (searchString.length < 3)
        return {data: []}

    const {data}  = await axios.get(`/search?q=${searchString}`)
    return data;
}
```

We can't use a hook inside a conditional - so I put the condition into my API calling function.

This almost works. If I enter a short query string, there is no API request made and I get an empty array back for the `data`. Yay!

But - `isLoading` will flip to `true` briefly - even though there is no HTTP request being made. So my loading indicator shows when there is no actual network activity.

Am I misunderstanding how to best solve my use case, is there a way to enure that `isLoading` will return false if there is no HTTP activity?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The key was to use [Dependent Queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries)

So, in my main component, I create a boolean and pass that to the `enabled` option of the `useQuery` hook:

```js
const isLongEnough = searchString.length > 3;
const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(['search', searchString], getSearchResults, {enabled: isLongEnough});
```

and the API calling method is simply the API call - not any conditional:

```js
const getSearchResults = async (_, searchString) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/search?q=${searchString}`);
    return data;
}
```

The docs describe dependent queries as a solution for loading data from subsequent API endpoints, but the `enable` option can accept any boolean. In this case - if the search query string is long enough.

Comment: I think your `isLongEnough` should be like this:

`const isLongEnough = searchString.length > 3;`

Answer (score 2):

There's another option which is to use `queryClient.fetchQuery` API, which gives you the ability to conditionally call the query to fetch the data.

```
function Example2() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error;

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          try {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const posts = await queryClient.fetchQuery(
              ["postsUsingFetchQuery"],
              {
                queryFn: () =>
                  axios
                    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
                    .then((res) => res.data)
              }
            );
            setData(posts);
          } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
          }
          setIsLoading(false);
        }}
      >
        Fetch posts using fetchQuery{" "}
      </button>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      {data?.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <span>{post.id}-&nbsp;</span>
            <div>{post.title}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the button click handler, we’ve added the implementation to fetch the posts using queryClient.fetchQuery.

You can read more from this [link](https://www.js-howto.com/react-query-how-to-fetch-queries-conditionally/).

Comment: Absolutely - I think the implementation you're suggesting there would be much simpler of an onClick as opposed to making an API call on render time.

Comment: One suggestion - there is a lot of code in your answer that's not strictly to do with answering the question. How to handle errors, the opinion that the results are saved to state, and rendered are all additional - making it an immediately usable code block, but it's harder to see the important thing you're calling out

Comment: Agree, at the same time you have a complete working component, you can take the code and play with it...