# How to initialize router before rendering anything in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js, react-query

I'm using react-query, when I get the id from the url and try to call it inside getSubject, it passes an undefined value http://localhost:3000/api/subject/undefined

but when I click a link from another component to get in this subject component it works but if refresh the page it does not work.

```
  const router = useRouter()

  const { id } = router.query

  const { data } = useQuery('subjects', async () => await getSubject(id))

  return value...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Conditionally calling an API using React-Query hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397534/conditionally-calling-an-api-using-react-query-hook)? You can use [Dependent Queries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries) so the query is only run if `id` is set, i.e. `{ enabled: !!id }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getServerSideProps` in this case. It has access to query params. On top of that you [can prefetch data on the server side too](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr).

```js
export interface PageProps {
  id: string;
}

export function Page({ id }: PageProps ) {
  const { data } = useQuery('subjects', async () => await getSubject(id))
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<PageProps > = async ({
  params,
}) => {
  const { id } = params;

  return {
    props: {
      id,
    },
  };
};
```

If you still want to use router, you can wait for `router.isReady` flag. When it is `true`, query params should be parsed.