# Conditional call hook to server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, trpc.io

I would like to have a component that show fake data and if the user choose some config it will call the server using TRPC:

```js
const { date } = useDateStore();
const [config, setConfig] = useState<configDTO | undefined>(undefined);
const [data, setData] = useState<Budget>(fake);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      try {
        if (isDemo || config == undefined) {
          setData(fake);
        } else {
          const response = api.dashboard.getBudgetById.useQuery({
            id: config.id,
            date: date,
          });
          if (response.data) {
            setData(response.data);
          } else {
            console.log(response)
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors here
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData(); // Call the fetchData function on mount and when config changes
  }, [config, date]); // Add date as a dependency if it's needed
```

My problem is that `api.dashboard.getBudgetById.useQuery` is a hook so it can't be in an other hook like useEffect and it's not async too. How I can conditionally call the server ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally calling an API using React-Query hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397534/conditionally-calling-an-api-using-react-query-hook)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `enabled` flag in `useQuery`.

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

[Conditionally calling an API using React-Query hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397534/conditionally-calling-an-api-using-react-query-hook)